# How do you cause a longer vibration from System sounds default vibration

Tags: iphone, vibration

I want to create a vibration but not of the normal length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done with the official SDK. The only way to trigger vibration is using a call to the following function, which unfortunately does not take any other parameters.

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
```

Maybe there's a way to do it for jailbroken iPhones, but no that I'm aware of.